# How to get the name of the current controller into my helper function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am still new to Rails and I have the following `section_links` that serve as the main navigation for my Rails app:

```
<%= section_link(Organisation.model_name.human(:count => 2), 'organisations', organisations_path) %>
<%= section_link(Person.model_name.human(:count => 2), 'people', people_path) %>
<%= section_link(Project.model_name.human(:count => 2), 'projects', projects_path) %>           
<%= section_link(Invoice.model_name.human(:count => 2), 'invoices', invoices_path) %>       
<%= section_link(Payment.model_name.human(:count => 2), 'payments', payments_path) %>
```

I also wrote this very basic helper function:

```
def section_link(title, section, path)
  options = {}  
  options[:class] = 'current' if section == controller_name
  link_to title, path, options
end
```

Is there any way to DRY up this helper function, so I can say something like this to make a link:

`<%= section_link("Organisations") %>`

I've been trying this for a couple of hours but I don't know how to pass the name of the current controller into my helper function.

Thanks for any help with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
def section_link(model)
   title = model.singularize.capitalize.constantize.model_name.human(:count => 2)
   section = model.downcase.pluralize
   path = {controller: model.pluralize.downcase, action: :index }
   options = {}  
   options[:class] = 'current' if section == controller_name
   link_to title, path, options
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try: [params[:controller] or controller.controller_name](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=29677)

```
<%= section_link(params[:controller], Organisation.model_name.human(:count => 2), 'organisations', organisations_path) %>

def section_link(current_controller, title, section, path)
 options = {}  
 options[:class] = 'current' if section == controller_name
 link_to title, path, options
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `request.params[:controller]` to get controller name in helper. I'm not sure if it work, but I'm sure you can get controller name from params.

Answer (score 1):

```
def current_link_to label, path, options = nil
    options ||= {} 
    options[:class] =  [options[:class], (current_page?(path) ? "active" : nil)].compact.join(" ")
    link_to label, path, options
end
```

Comment: `current_page?` => didn't know that one, very handy